# cache control not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, caching

I've placed a simple cache control in my .htaccess file:

```
#cache css and javascript files for one week  
<FilesMatch ".(js|css)$">  
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"  
</FilesMatch>
```

When I test the desktop site at Google's Page Site tester: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights ... it shows the javascript and images are being cached properly. However, when I test my mobile website, the caching isn't working. My htaccess file is contained in the public_html directory alongside all my desktop files (ie. public_html/index.html, public_html/images/, public_html/css/, public_html/.htaccess etc.) My mobile site is contained here: public_html/mobile/.

Would I need to add a second .htaccess file to the mobile directory to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use .htaccess file of html5 boilerplate. It is highly optimised for cache,gzip,cross-domain ajax plus a lot of features.

Also do check whether mod_deflate is on or not.

You don't need any additional .htaccess file just use a single file in the root of your directory.